# Division in Android Gone Wrong Value

Tags: java, android, calculator, calculation, integer-division

When I divided the large number into a small number then the division is correct but when I write the small number to divide a large number the answer returns wrong. In my scenario, the small number always be first. here is my code this code return 7.4074074074074075E-6 but the correct result is 0.0000074074.

```
    double itf = 0.0;
    double a = 4.0;
    double b = 540000;
    itf = a / b;
    Log.i(TAG, "savedata: outputvalue=" + itf);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("4");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("540000");

// 0.0000074074
a.divide(b, MathContext.DECIMAL128);
```

You should use a decimal type. double is outside the scope of support